# System.AccessViolationException unhandled with Hashtable class

Tags: c#, hashtable, access-violation

I am writing a program in c#. I am getting an `AccessViolationException` and I am not sure why. Plus my try and catch statement is not catching it.
here is my code :

```
static public Hashtable GetSpectrumFromTidas(int integrationTime, int maxWaveLength, int minWaveLength, double spectrometerAveragingFactor, string ipAddressTidas)
{
    Hashtable readValues = new Hashtable();
    int[] vals;
    //vals = new int[spectrometerDataSize];

    int numAverages;
    //if(integrationTime <100)
    numAverages = (int)Math.Floor((double)100 / integrationTime * spectrometerAveragingFactor) + 1;

    vals = tidas.readSpectrum(integrationTime, numAverages, 2, ipAddressTidas);

    try
    {
        for (int i = minWaveLength; i <= maxWaveLength; i++)
        {
            float data = tidas.getSpectrumData(i, ref vals) / numAverages;
            readValues.Add(i.ToString(), string.Format("{0:N}", data));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
    return readValues;
}
```

Now it does not always happen,  just sometimes. and the `Hashtable` class I am using is from the Collection lib.

it happens at the line `readvalues.add(....)`

Comment: An error that occurs at runtime this case its called an `Exception` (*this is how errors manifest themselves in .net*). Include the `Message`, the `Type`, the `StackTrace`, and repeat this recursively across `InnerException`s all the way down. Use the  [edit] link on your question to include that detail, *do not* include it as a comment. Please also read [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask). You can print out the relevant details using `err.ToString()`

Comment: Not related, but `Hashtable` is a class that's more associated with .NET 1.1 than anything. If you can replace it with `Dictionary<int, float>` you'd likely have better performance and type-safety.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. The bug is likely in `getSpectrumData`.

Comment: Your program is suffering a corruption and there is no point continuing, this is intended. This is most likely a memory corruption and caused by any number of things, like unsafe code or bad pointer, multi threading. We cannot help you with this question, you will have to forensically debug your application